# Differenciated sampling rate by group

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, sampling

For a machine learning model training, I'm trying to sample a dataframe that has a grouping variable, so that each group is treated with a different sampling rule. For instance, my data:

```
df = data.frame(value = 1:10, label=c("a", "a", "b", rep("c", 7)))
```

For groups of size under, say, 3, I want to take the whole group and no more, and for bigger groups I want to take a sample of size 3 without replacement.

So here, the result could be: `df[c(1:3, 6,9,10),]`

If I use `group_by` and `sample_n`, I get an size error. I thought of going "manual" with splits and differentiated sampling and then bind again the rows, but is there a more efficient and direct way?

Comment: Are you open to *data.table* solutions? If so, you could do something like `df[, if(.N <= 3) .SD else .SD[sample(3)], by=label]` I think.

Comment: @thelatemail i never used it but why not? but i get an error with your code (unused argument by=label)

Comment: @agenis - you need to install/load the *data.table* package first, and convert to a data.table via `setDT(df)` first. The package extends standard data.frames.

Comment: ok with the setDT it worked thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the size of the group `n()`, in `sample_n`.

```
df %>% group_by(label) %>% sample_n(min(n(), 3))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   label [3]
#  value label     n
#  <int> <fct> <int>
#1     1 a         2
#2     2 a         2
#3     3 b         1
#4     5 c         7
#5    10 c         7
#6     4 c         7
```

Comment: oh nice, using the count by group and min

Comment: addtionally, no need for the extra mutate step at all: `sample_n(min(n(), 3))
`